# How to hide/show text fields based on options selected in a drop down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to hide/show certain fields based on what is selected in a dropdown. 
I have the following code.

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    alert("handler called");
    $("#name").hide();
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#selection").on('change', function() {
        alert("handler called1");
        if ($("#selection").val() == "day")
        {
            $("#name").show();
        }

      });
});
});
```

My HTML is

```
<div class="selection" id = "selection">
   <tbody><td><label>selection</label></td>
<td><select class="selection"></select></td>
   </tbody>            
</div>

<div class="name" id = "name">
<tbody><td><label>Name</label></td><td><input type="text" </input></td>
</tbody>
</div>
```

The

```
alert("handler called")
```

works fine. And the

```
$("#name").hide();
```

also works. But the second part where the actual selection based hide/show is not working. I guess Im not able to capture the selection made in the dropdown menu. 
Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you are binding document-ready handler in the button click handler and since document has already loaded event binding never happens for `select`.

*Use*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button").click(function() {
        alert("handler called");
        $("#name").hide();
    });
    $(".selection").on('change', function() {
        alert("handler called1");
        if ($(this).val() == "day") {
            $("#name").show();
        }
    });
});
```

Also you need to use [Class Selector `(".class")`](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) since you are using `<select class="selection"></select>`

Comment: I changed my code accordingly. I realize now that the selection value is not being captured and so my if statement is not being executed at all. Any ideas on where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Another issue I noticed is that the hide/show is working only once. Only for the first on click event the whole hide/show works and when I submit the form and click the button again, the hide/show do not work. Any reason why?

Comment: @pal, What are you doing in form submit? and important `your html seems invalid`